# Beginners help to Angular JS debugging via console errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plnkr.co

AngularJS is new to me (and difficult). So I would like to learn how to debug.
Currently I'm following a course and messed something up. Would like to know how to interpret the console error and solve the bug.

[plnkr.co code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ojkSRZ?p=preview)

index.html

```
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>

    {{ username }}
    <form action="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
      <input  type="search" 
              required placeholder="Username to find" 
              ng-model="username"/>
      <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>

    <div>
      <p>Username found: {{user.name + error}}</p>
      <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{user.gravatar_id}}" title="{{user.name}}"/>    
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

  var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

    var onUserComplete = function(response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = "could not fetch data";
    };

    $scope.search = function(username) {
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
        .then(onUserComplete, onError);
    };

    $scope.username = "angular";
    $scope.message = "GitHub Viewer";   };

  app.controller("MainController", MainController);

}());
```

The console only says

> searchUser:1 GET http://run.plnkr.co/lZX5It1qGRq2JGHL/searchUser? 404
>   (Not Found)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, `action` you have written this

`<form action="searchUser"`

What this does is it will try to submit to a url with currentHostName\searchUser, so in this case your are testing on plunker hence the plunker url.

You can change the url where the form is submitted. Incase you want to search ajax wise then you dont even need to specify the action part. You can let your service/factory make that call for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ng-submit page is being redirected before the response arrives and you provided any action `URL` as `searchUser` which is not a state or any html file so it being used to unknown address, it is async call so it will take some time you can use input types as `button` instead of `submit`.

[Here is the working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/EthC4CPhYeQihEn1UB9M?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="githubViewer">

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>

    {{ username }}
    <form >
      <input  type="search" 
              required placeholder="Username to find" 
              ng-model="username"/>
      <input type="button"  ng-click="search(username)" value="search">
    </form>

    <div>
      <p>Username found: {{user.name + error}} {{user}}</p>
      <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{user.gravatar_id}}" title="{{user.name}}"/>    
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no need of **action="searchUser"** in your html.

Comment: ya you are right just forgot to remove , just copy pasted that's why

Answer (score 1):

Though not exactly related to debugging this particular error, there is a chrome extension "ng-inspector" which is very useful for angularJS newbies. You can view the value each of your angular variable scopewise and their value. Hope it helps!
Here is the link of the chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?hl=en

Comment: I have already mentioned that in the very first line of my answer. Just wanted to let the person know of an another debugging tool.

Comment: OP asked for debugging but it was not related to that in accordance with OP perspective @ishaaggarwal is right